# Converting Microsecond time to Millisecond time

Tags: java, api, time, java-8

I am receiving a time-stamp from a GPS receiver and it is represented in microsecond time after seconds:

```
00:12:34.567891
```

Java 7 and below only use millisecond time, so I could split the string and parse the microsecond portion to millisecond, but that seems ridiculous.

Java 8 operates on nanosecond precision, but if I use a DateTimeFormatter with a pattern of "HH:mm:ss.nnnnnn", will the section after the "." be considered in terms of nanosecond?

Essentially how to I take my microsecond timestamp and convert it to a total number of milliseconds.

Comment: Java7 has [`TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#NANOSECONDS)... and `System.nanoTime();`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can help you, is by default since Java7

```
TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.convert(567891, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

carefully give as parameter the time parsed as long..

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping not to have to split on the time-stamp. Seems like this should be easier.

Comment: The Questions seems to be asking for a total number of milliseconds in the entire span-of-time rather than just the fraction of a second seen in this Answer. But the Question is unclear and poorly phrased.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Duration.between( 
    LocalTime.MIN , 
    LocalTime.parse( "00:12:34.567891" )   
).toMillis()
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/mW80LA).

> 754567

## java.time

Your input does *not* appear to be a GPS timestamp. You should determine and document an explanation of your data source.

The word “timestamp” usually means a point on the timeline, a date plus time-of-day plus time zone (or offset-from-UTC). In contrast, your `00:12:34.567891` appears to be a span of time, specifically twelve minutes, thirty-four seconds, and about a half second more (0.567891 seconds).

Assuming you will not have any input greater than 24 hours long, I suggest parsing as a `LocalTime` object.

```
String input = "00:12:34.567891" ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( input );
```

Represent the span of time as a `Duration`.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( LocalTime.MIN , lt ) ;
```

Generate a String representing the value of this [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) in [standard ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format. In this format of `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where the `P` marks the beginning, and the `T` separates any years-months-days portion from any hours-minutes-seconds portion.

```
PT12M34.567891S
```

By the way, your input string value is a poor choice of format for serializing a span-of-time value. Use the standard ISO 8601 format instead whenever possible.

You seem to be asking for this entire span of time as a count of milliseconds. Be aware this means data-loss as any [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond) or [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) in the fraction of a second are truncated to [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond).

```
long millis = d.toMillis() ;  // Consider entire span of time as milliseconds.
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/mW80LA).

> 754567

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).